# Indesign scripting: can't relink image

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I'm trying to come up with a simple script that relinks an image (eps file) in Indesign.

This is what I've come up with so far

```
//find item and get path
var myItem = app.activeDocument.links.item("MyCurrentimage.eps");
var myItemPath = myItem.filePath;
//define new image path
var newPath = "P:\\images\\otherfolder\\newimage.eps";
//relink
myItem.relink(myItemPath,newPath);
```

I keep getting a message saying "Cannot create the link resource from the given URI". Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Why does `newPath` have double slashes in the path?

Comment: I've tried both double and single but it doesn't make much difference. I still get the weird error.

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work by using `relink` with `new File()`

```
//target item
var itemIwantToReplace = app.activeDocument.links.item("MyCurrentimage.eps");
//relink
itemIwantToReplace.relink(new File("P:\\Images\\myNewImage.eps"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is really just a guess, but perhaps it sees your `newPath` as just a string, not a URI, so you need to pass an actual URL object.

```
var newPath = new URL("P:\images\otherfolder\newimage.eps");
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately now I get a different error saying "URL does not have a constructor"

Comment: Maybe it's a `new URI`  it wants?  That's not a thing, but maybe it is in InDesign?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var myItem = app.activeDocument.links.item("MyCurrentimage.eps");
var myItemPath = myItem.filePath;
var newPath = new File("P:\\images\\otherfolder\\newimage.eps");

myItem.relink(newPath);
```